# How to Count columns using where and like clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This is my ms-sql query -

```
  select COUNT(*) from InvoiceDetails where InvoiceId like '%XXX-SSS%'
```

how to write this same query in LINQ

Comment: Try following `InvoiceDetails.Count(a => a.InvoiceId.Contains("XXX-SSS")`

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
var count=_dbcontent.InvoiceDetails.Where(dr => dr.InvoiceId.Contains("XXX-SSS")).Count;
```

`Count`will do count of all records

Comment: `ToList` does not count the entries in the `Enumerable`. You still need a `.Count` or `.Count()` after that.

Comment: I'm still not sure if `ToList` is suitable at all. If you have a lot of entries that match the `Where`, you'll have unneccessary traffic between the client and the database as `ToList` pulls all entries down to the client.

Answer (score 2):

```
InvoiceDetails.Count(x => x.InvoiceId.Contains("XXX-SSS"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
InvoiceDetails.Count(el => el.InvoiceId.Contains("XXX-SSS"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The like operator is similar to contains function in Linq. so get count of records after filtering it.

```
YourDBContext.YourTableModel.Count(x=>x.YourColumn.Contains("YourValue"));
```

But this will only work if the columne is string type.

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple.

```
var yourEtityObject = 
(from t In InvoiceDetails 
where 
t.InvoiceId.Contains("XXX-SSS")
select t).Count();
```